# How to make a process wait in the background and be able to be killed by signal other than KILL

Tags: shell-script, signals

I want a script run in the background, take some actions for every hour. It should also quit if receiving a signal. And at last, it should perform some clean-up actions before quitting.

Based on the concept, I wrote something like the following:

```
trap 'clean_up; exit' SIGTERM
while true
do
    someActions
    sleep 1h
done
```

I ran the script by

```
./script &
```

I kill the script by

```
kill -SIGTERM <pid>
```

It turned out the script didn't work as expected. I think the reason is that you can kill a sleeping process only by `SIGKILL` signal. But on the other hand, you cannot trap a `SIGKILL` signal to do some cleanup before quitting.

So how can I make a process wait in the background and be able to quit when it receives a signal other than `SIGKILL`?

Comment: Show us a small script that you *have* tried. (Not something like)

Answer (score 1):

If by "didn't work as expected" you mean you wrote a SIGTERM handler and it did not fire for SIGTERM, **you've made a mistake in your code**.

Here's a working example:

```
#!/bin/bash

cleanup () {
        echo "goodbye!"
        exit 0
}

trap 'cleanup' SIGTERM

while sleep 1; do
        echo $BASHPID
done
```

Reacts as expected to `kill -SIGTERM`.  You can use any signal you want except, as you already know, SIGKILL, and SIGSTOP.